# Fetching shipment statuses for a user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I think the inherent relations in this query should be self-evident:

```
ShipmentStatus.joins(shipment: :shipment_users)
              .where("shipment_users.user_id = ?", user.id)
```

I have a feeling there's maybe a shorter way to express this. Can it be reduced?

Comment: What ActiveRecord relationships have been declared in `ShipmentStatus` and `ShipmentUsers`?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult without knowing exactly what the models and relations are. I'm guessing it's like this:

```
ShipmentUser hasMany Shipment
ShipmentStatus hasMany Shipment
Shipment belongsTo ShipmentUser
Shipment belongsTo ShipmentStatus
```

And `user.isKindOf? ShipmentUser` (and not other model).

Then you could do:

```
user.shipments.joins(shipment: :shipment_status)
```

If that's not the case (e.g. `user` is another model), I think there isn't a shorter way to express it, but I rather have the conditions in a Hash instead of strings, like this:

```
ShipmentStatus.joins(shipment: :shipment_users)
              .where(shipment_users: { user_id: user.id })
```

This way it's easier to add other conditions in the same `where()` or merge with defaults.